# Fetch title from url using Google App Script

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I would like to input a url on a Google Spreadsheet and then magically this would fetch the title using a Google Apps Script. Do you know how to implement this?

Comment: If you had a simple `onEdit()` trigger, that would monitor your spreadsheet for edits.  Then it could take the URL, make an HTTPS Request with `UrlFetchApp.fetch()` and get the title.  This question is to general for stackoverflow.  You can join the [Google Apps Script Group](https://plus.google.com/u/0/communities/102471985047225101769) and ask a question there.

Comment: Thank you, @SandyGood. I will head to the Google Apps Script Group for further questions.

Answer (score 7):

You can also just do importxml function in the spreadsheet :

```
=IMPORTXML("URL","//title")
```

Comment: Yep, this is the fastest and simplest solution. Great input, Aurielle Perlmann. Thanks!

Comment: Thanks! Yes, I did the first time, but it seems that I don't have enough reputation to display it.

Comment: If for some reason your document has multiple titles I suggest using =IMPORTXML("URL","//head[position()<=1]/title")

Answer (score 3):

Here is the magic ;)

Set up `onEdit` trigger,

```
function onEdit(e)
{
  var url = e.value;
  var urlData = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url).getContentText();
  var xmldoc = Xml.parse(urlData, true);
  var title = xmldoc.html.head.getElements("title")[0].getText();
  Logger.log('URL Title: '+ title);
  Browser.msgBox('URL Title: '+ title);
}
```

Tada !

Comment: Thanks, iJay. I will try this solution.

Comment: Does this actually work? I haven't gotten onEdit triggers to do url fetches. See https://code.google.com/p/google-apps-script-issues/issues/detail?can=2&start=0&num=100&q=&colspec=Stars%20Opened%20ID%20Type%20Status%20Summary%20Component%20Owner&groupby=&sort=&id=185

Comment: No, it doesn't work. You can do it if you create an installable trigger, but not from a trigger that fires based on being named onEdit().

Answer (score 1):

```
=HYPERLINK(IMPORTXML("https://www.https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moon_landing";"//title"))
```

So you have a highlighted, clickable Hyperlink ;)